# sqlite memory usage issue for db file size > 2GB when creating index

Tags: python, linux, sqlite

I have a simple sqlite database with two tables.

```
Table 1:
    Col1: int index; 
    Col2: text; 
    Col3: int;
Table 2:
    Col1: int; 
    Col2: int;  
    Col3: int;
```

The first table goes up to millions of rows. Table 2 can have hundreds of millions rows. Table 1, Col2 is indexed after all data are entered. Indexes are also  created for Table 2 col1, col2.

The index creation works fine when the database file size is small - < 3.5GB.   When the database file system is > 3.5GB, I will see memory error.

This is Linux system, on 32 bit kernel, the file size >2GB seems to cause memory error during index creation.  On 64 bit kernel, the limit is > 3.5GB.

From "top" program, I see the VM and RSS usage goes up to 3.5GB on 64 bit system before it die.

Have anyone seen this?  Any suggestions on how to work around the issue.  Does Anyone have luck with sqlite with Multi GB file size + index creation?

Comment: Are you creating the index in the SQLite version embedded in Python, or with the `sqlite3` command-line tool? Which SQLite version is this? Could you try with [the latest version](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)?

Comment: CL, I use the sqlite code from 3.7.14.1  2012-10-4 release.   The sqlite module is embedded inside python.   SQL command is entered via Python.   Memory usage is fine until I issue "create index" command after all the data are entered.   I will try the latest version.  Have you tried create index with multi-GB size file/millions/hundred millions row?   Do you have any memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use a newer SQLite version to avoid eating up memory. (3.7.16 works for me.)

Ensure that there is enough free space on `/tmp`, or move `TMPDIR` elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks the suggestions.  I tried upgrade to the latest 3.8.x and it still doesn't help.  The system still encounter out of memory error when creating index.  The table for the creating index has 200+ million rows in it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found it was caused by the [temp_store pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store). I had it set to

```
pragma temp_store = memory;
```

but clearly there is a limit to how much memory is available.  I fixed it using

```
pragma temp_store = file;
```

If you know that a particular index will cause a problem like this, then you can just set the pragma around the "create" statement and change it again afterwards:

```
pragma temp_store = file;
create index if not exists table_1_index on table_1(Col1);
pragma temp_store = memory;
```